# Projective but not free (exercise from Adkin - Weintraub)

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

This is exercise 38 from Chapter 3. Modules and Vector Spaces in Algebra by Adkins and Weintraub (GTM). How do you solve this problem?

Let 
\begin{equation*}
R = \lbrace f : [0, 1] \to \Re : f \;\text{ is continuous and} \; f (0) = f (1) \rbrace  
\end{equation*}
and let
\begin{equation*}
M = \lbrace f : [0, 1]\to \Re : f \;\text{is continuous and} \; f (0) = - f (1) \rbrace.
\end{equation*}
Then $R$ is a ring under addition and multiplication of functions, and $M$ is an $R$-module. Show that $M$ is a projective $R$-module that is not free.

Comment: You should probably ask this on math.stackexchange.com...

Comment: This site is not for asking the solutions of exercises (read the FAQ). There are some exceptions, for example when you give more background, show your results and in particular when the exercise is actually a hard problem.

Comment: I should add that Martin really means 'hard', as in gnarly problems out of Lang or similar.

Comment: Exercises in elementary graduate texts are usually (though not in absolutely all cases) just exercises.   It's best to spend time thinking it through rather than asking other people.

Comment: Hint: Möbius band.